# How is a sites last activity date determined?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to figure out what triggers an update to a sites last activity date. I have republished a page in one site yesterday but the last activity date doesn't reflect this. I also tried uploading a document on another and it failed to update the last activity date.

Does anyone know what specifically triggers an update to the last activity date? I am reading the date from the SharePoint admin centers list of active sites.

Comment: How long did you wait before checking? It's quite possible that the last activity date is actually sourced from the search service which takes time to index.

Comment: @CallumCrowley I waited roughly 24 hours